# Java strange CSV behaviour

Tags: java

I am fairly inexperienced with java. I am using the following code to read the following CSV file. Strangely, the output of `line[0].length()` is 2. Even stranger, `Character.getNumericValue(line[0].charAt(0))` prints `-1` and `Character.getNumericValue(line[0].charAt(1))` prints `2`. All consecutive lines are correctly read. What is the reason for this?

Code:

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(file));
input.useDelimiter("\n");
while (input.hasNext()) {
    String[] line = input.next().split(",");
    System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(line[0].charAt(0)) + " " + Character.getNumericValue(line[0].charAt(1)) + " " + line[1].trim());
    break;
}
```

CSV:

```
2,ID
3,IF
4,ID
5,Error
6,REAL
7,NUM
8,REAL
9,Error
11,White space
12,Blank
13,Error
```

Output:

```
-1 2 ID
```

Comment: Err the code you are showing prints 0/0 then 0/1. It doesnt print entry 0 char 0 twice.

Comment: And when you read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-char- ... you find that -1 means: not a numeric value. So most likely, in the beginning of your file, there is something that doesnt belong there. How did you create that file, and are you SURE it really starts like the table here?

Comment: Use a hex editor to examine each octet of your file.

Comment: My guess is that the first line might start with a byte-order mark. We can't really tell any more than that - as Basil says, have a look at the exact bytes in your file (not with a text editor).

Comment: @BasilBourque yes typo

Comment: @JonSkeet I used excel to create the file. Is it normal for excel to add the byte-order mark to csv files?

Comment: @t348575: I don't know, but I wouldn't be surprised. I would focus on understanding what's in the file first though. I'd also strongly recommend that you pass a Charset to the Scanner constructor, rather than just using the platform default encoding.